# How to give json response dynamically..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, openlayers-3

Here is the json response

```
[{"lat": "36.15900011", "lon": "-115.17205183"}, {"lat": "36.15899561", "lon": "-115.17276155"}]
```

And below code given this error:

```
TypeError: item is undefined
...: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([item.lon , item.lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:...
```

below the code inside the `<script>`

```
    $.ajax({
     url:'parser', success:function(response){
      $(document).ready(function(){
      var jsonlen = response.length;
      for (var i=0; i<=jsonlen; i++){
        var item = response[i];
        var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({  
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([item.lon , item.lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
        name:'Null Island',
        rainfall:500
      })
        var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        // empty vector
      })
      vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);
      }
```

I don't know how to give json response continuously to `iconFeature`

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question.  Are you trying to figure out why you're getting the error?

Comment: Also, why are you adding a document ready handler in the success function?  Why not just run the code?

Comment: @Smeegs Honestly .. i just don't know anything about javascript. I just copied this code from another SO question. All i want is ` I have the response containing lat and lon , I don't know how to give lat and lon to Marker` .. that is it

Comment: Okay, I'll try to help you with your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, unwrap your code from the handler, it makes no sense here.  I've amended it in the code.

Second, your for loop will run even if the length is empty. That's why you're getting undefined.
You need to use just less than, not less than or equal.
Because, if the length is zero, and `i` initiates at zero, then the conditional will be true and response[0] will be called, even though the response is an empty array.  Returning `undefined`

Third (and I can't help you with this), you have to check the response to make sure the data is present.  It doesn't seem like it is.

```
  $.ajax({
     url: 'parser',
     success: function (response) {
         var jsonlen = response.length - 1;         
         for (var i = 0; i < jsonlen; i++) {
             var item = response[i];
             var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
                 geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([item.lon, item.lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
                 name: 'Null Island',
                 rainfall: 500
             });
             var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
                 // empty vector
             })
             vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);
         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: I think you also have to call `JSON.parse`?, or set the dataType to JSON

Comment: @Smeegs i am not getting any error in my firebug rightnow but the marker not displaying ..

Comment: @ZenMaster Did you try adding a breakpoint to analyze what's going on? https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging http://michaelsync.net/2007/09/30/firebug-tutorial-script-tab-javascript-debugging

Comment: Ok .. got it. i need to give dynamically `vectorsource` also .. shall i give like `vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature++); ??`

Comment: i need icon feature also dynamic iconFeature1, iconFeature2 .. like that  .. Can you help me?